# How to maximize scalar product using Lagrangian methods

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

maximize $U(x) = u \cdot x$ with respect to $p \cdot x = w$

given that $u, p, x \in \mathbb{R}^L_+$, $w \in \mathbb{R_+}$.

I can solve it classically:

\begin{align}
u \cdot x &= \sum u_i x_i \\
&= \sum \frac{u_i}{p_i} p_i x_i\\
&\le \max{\frac{u_i}{p_i}} \sum p_j x_j\\
&= \max{\frac{u_i}{p_i}} \cdot w
\end{align}

with equality when $x = \frac{w}{p_i} e_i$ where $i = \text{argmax}_j \frac{u_j}{p_j}$ and $e_i$ is the $i$-th basis vector.

But I would like to see a proof using Lagrange multipliers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=u_1x_1+\ldots+u_nx_n$ and $g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=p_1x_1+\ldots+p_nx_n$, where $\textbf{u}\ge 0$ and $\textbf{p}> 0$ (coordinate-wise).

Solve

\begin{align}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\max\,\,\, &f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \qquad\qquad\text{subject to} \\
&g(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = a \\
&x_1 \ge 0 \\
&...\\
&x_n \ge 0 \\
\end{align}
This is a constrained optimization problem with inequality constraints, which is solved by Kuhn-Tucker method ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) and [original paper](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/berkeley-symposium-on-mathematical-statistics-and-probability/Proceedings-of-the-Second-Berkeley-Symposium-on-Mathematical-Statistics-and/chapter/Nonlinear-Programming/bsmsp/1200500249)). We use $\lambda$ as multiplier on the equality constrain and $\mu_i$ as multipliers on the non-negativity constraints.
Kuhn-Tucker conditions:

\begin{align}
u_i &= \lambda p_i + \mu_i, \text{ for } i=1,...,n \\
a &= p_1x_1+\ldots+p_nx_n \\
\mu_i &\le 0, \text{ for } i=1,...,n \\
\mu_i x_i &= 0, \text{ for } i=1,...,n \\
\end{align}
Clearly, not all $x_i$ equal to $0$. Let $i^*$ denote the index for which $x_{i^*}>0$. Then $\mu_{i^*}=0$ and $\lambda = \frac{u_{i^*}}{p_{^*}}$. It then follows that for indices $i\ne i^*$ we must have $\mu_i = u_i - \frac{u_{i^*}}{p_{^*}}p_i$ and
$\frac{\mu_i}{p_i} = \frac{u_i}{p_i} - \frac{u_{i^*}}{p_{^*}}$ which must be non-positive ($p_i>0$ by assumption).

Thus, $i^*$ must be the index for which $\frac{u_i}{p_i}$ is the largest. And for all other indices $x_i=0$ because $\mu_i >0$, so that $x_{i^*} = \frac{a}{p_{^*}}$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as posed, has no solution unless $u=cp$ are collinear vectors in which case it becomes trivial. Let's fix some notation:

$f(x_1,x_2) = u_1x_1+u_2x_2$ be the objective function,

$g(x_1,x_2)=p_1x_2+ p_2x_2$ and $g(x_1,x_2)=a$ be the constraint (the case of $\mathbb{R^d}$ is similar).

Wlog $p_1\ne 0$. Solve for $x_1 = \frac{a}{p_1}-\frac{p_1}{p_2}x_2$ and substitute

$F(x_2) = u_1\frac{a}{p_1} + (u_2-u_1\frac{p_2}{p_1})x_2$ is the new objective function. If $u\neq cp$, then the term in parenthesis is not $0$ and $F$ is unbounded.

If we try to apply the Lagrange multiplier method, we find conditions: 
$\textbf{u} = \lambda\textbf{p}$ which does not have a solution.

Comment: You're quite right, I want to add $x_i \ge 0$ as a feasibility constraint, otherwise there is an arbitrage. But all vectors in the problem are on $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: Peteris, this changes the nature of the problem. It's constrained optimization with inequality constraints. I added another solution and some references.